# Por que el nombre de usuario no es unico?

Tags: discusión, soporte

Viendo alguna preguntas y respuestas me encontré con un usuario que tiene el mismo nombre usuario que el mio **Christian** y fue allí cuando me puse a pensar ¿por que el nombre de usuario no es único? Creo que sería un problema , ya que si tienes una buena reputación ya serás conocido y que alguien más se tenga el mismo *username* no me parece correcto.
Una vez leído los argumentos, mi opinión es distinta, ahora pienso que debería de haber una forma en poder identificar al usuario de una forma fácil, como agregando su **id** al lado de su nombre, de esta forma *Christian#183682* ya que, esto si representaría un *username*

Comment: Un nombre no es único. En el mundo hay miles de personas llamadas Christian, Álvaro, o Juan. Si no se limita el nombre en la vida real, ¿por qué se va a limitar en un sitio web? Los argumentos que presentas no me parecen de peso. Si dijeras que tienen tu nombre y tu foto, entonces sí que habría un problema, pero estaríamos hablando de otra cosa (que sí va en contra de las normas de la comunidad). Pero sólo compartir el nombre es algo normal online y offline.

Comment: Otro problema parecido pero no igual, es el contrario: en lugar de varias personas con el mismo nombre, una persona con múltiples nombres (múltiples cuentas) que se usan para votarse entre sí. Algo que sí ocurre más a menudo en el sitio y que es un problema grave, que muchas veces acaba con la destrucción de las cuentas y la pérdida de puntos.

Comment: Bueno en la primera parte es verdad, sin embargo en el mundo el nombre completo consiste en : nombres y apellidos y esto es con el fin de identificar mejor a la persona, lo cual creo conveniente en este sitio, una forma de identificar a la persona, como es el caso de muchos usuarios con una alta reputación.

Comment: Para identificar a una persona en la vida real no se usa el nombre y apellido, se utilizan IDs y carnets de identidad (DNI, SSN, etc.) porque el nombre es relativo. Por ejemplo, si busco "Álvaro Montoro" en Google, veré que hay varias docenas (y yo que pensaba que tenía un nombre único ). En el caso de Stack Overflow hay varios IDs: uno es numérico otorgado al usuario según se registra (el mío es 250, el tuyo es 183782), el otro es el email utilizado en el registro que debe ser único.

Comment: Si los identificar paso por alto eso, y por que no agregar ese id como discriminador,al igual que hace discord, cambiar la forma de mostrar el nombre  a **Christian#183682** creo que de esa forma seria mejor identificar al usuario

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro No se deberia comparar nombre de usuario por nombre de personas, porque un nombre de usuario puede ser como dice Cristian "*Christian#183682*". Aun asi creo que seria buena idea, pero supongo que ya se dieron los argumentos necesarios para no implementarlo, ya que sino se hubiera hecho desde el principio

Comment: Sobre lo otro de identificar un usuario, por lo que he visto, la unica forma actual que se tiene para buscar un usuario, es por nombre en esta [seccion](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users), lo que diferencia seria la foto, informacion, etiquetas, reputacion o si es mod o no. Aun asi si esto no podria ser implementado, al menos en esa seccon se deberia implementar el ID unico de cada usuario para poder distingir ya que hay casos de que algunas son similares entre usuarios

Comment: @Juan Rivera, cierto , estaría bien ponerlo en esa [sección](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users)

Comment: El problema que veo es que estáis mezclando dos conceptos diferentes: el nombre/id de usuario es único y el nombre mostrado no tiene porque serlo (por el mismo motivo que en la vida real hay personas con el mismo nombre sin ser la misma persona). De todos modos, lo que estáis sugiriendo que se haga está fuera del alcance de lo que podemos hacer en este foro. Deberíais crear un post en el [meta de StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Creo que la gente está demasiado acostumbrada a que los nombres de usuario sean *únicos*... cuando no hay razón para que eso sea así. De hecho, siempre me ha parecido muy mala idea que los nombres de usuario sean únicos, visibles y sean lo que se utilice para iniciar sesión en los sitios, puesto que estás dando el 50% de tus datos privados para entrar a la cuenta! Un nombre de usuario es eso... el nombre por el que alguien quiere ser conocido, nada más. Si te haces *famoso* en el sitio, la gente sabrá de quien se habla por el contexto, no veo necesidad de dar datos extras para identificarse

Comment: Les doy un juego: Intenten encontrar a Juan buscando [aca](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users). Pista: tiene una foto con color marron y 0 de reputación

Comment: @JuanRivera encontre a uno pero es [Juan Gonzales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/223385/juan-gonzalez), también encontré encontré [JuanJota](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/221154/juanjota)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La reputación de un usuario siempre aparece al lado de su imagen y nombre, por lo que no es un problema que te confundan con otra persona. Además, el hecho de que no sea único permite que lo puedas cambiar si así lo consideras.

Por otro lado, si quieres usar tu ID para realizar búsquedas puedes hacerlo: En el campo de búsqueda puedes escribir `user:183782` y te mostrará las preguntas/respuestas hechas por ti

Comment: Gracias, aun que considero que aprenderse un numero es mucho más difícil que un nombre, por lo que resulta más fácil hacer una busquedad por un nombre que ves a menudo